# How do I skip minibuffer completion in `completing-read`?

Tags: completion

In a function X that calls `completing-read`, I'd like to be able to call X and pass in a constant input without invoking the minibuffer. From the [emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Minibuffer-Completion.html), it seems I'm supposed to `flet` `completing-read-function`, but I'm not sure the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the constant input to be optional, you can declare the function as taking an optional argument and then check if the argument is actually passed: if it is, go ahead and use it; if it isn't, then call `completing-read`.

Something like this:

```el
(defun X (&optional foo)
  (message (or foo (completing-read "Enter foo value: " nil)))
```

where I assume that the value of `foo` is a string.

If you call it with `M-: (X)`, then `foo` will be `nil` and you will get the prompt. If you call it with `M-: (X "bar")` then no prompt will be issued and the value of `foo` will be the string `bar`.

Comment: (Nit:) `(when (null foo))` = `(unless foo)`.

Comment: Hi @NickD, the function X in question is `counsel-org-goto`, which isn't my function. I'd like to refrain from changing it, and instead, when it calls `completing-read`, have a user-supplied constant value automatically fed in.

Comment: You should have specified that in your question. I do not have time to check (and I know nothing about counsel), so I'm afraid I can't help. Maybe somebody else will provide an answer.